# Как изменить позицию ScrollView при запуске фрагмента программно?

Tags: java, android, scrollview

В `onCreateView` добавил следующий код и ничего не работает, а если создаю кнопку myButton и добавляю ему слушателя при нажатии вставив тот же самый код то все работает, как сделать так чтоб все работало не нажимая на кнопку автоматически при создании

`myScroll = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.myScroll);
myScroll.scrollTo(0, 0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28173911/3212712):

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Тут код выполнится чрез 0.5с
        myScroll.scrollTo(0,0);
    }
}, 500);
```

?

Comment: спасибо, работает

Comment: можно попробовать без `Handler` - `myScroll.postDelayed(new Runnable(){...},500);` :)

Comment: @AbrogPetrovich, да что-то такое у меня в голове было, но гугл мне такую конструкцию выдавать упорно не хотел. А IDE не запущена)

Answer (score 1):

Если вызывать `myScroll` сразу - он не успевает инициализироваться.
Попробуйте так:

```
    myScroll.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myScroll.scrollTo(0,0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: не помогло, это ведь в `onCreateView ` нужно добавить или я не правильно понял?